# electric-circuits

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits

Why can't you connect the + of a device to one battery and the - to another battery (and have it work)?[image]

Comment: You might be interested to look at this too [Could this open electric circuit work?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/121723/could-this-open-electric-circuit-work#comment248679_121723).

Answer (score 1):

If you want that bulb to work then you should have complete circuit which is not there in the diagram you have show

[image: complete circuit]

what you are telling is completely possible if circuit is complete as shown below:
[image]

Comment: but in my shown we have voltage difference

Comment: @user50430 you should read **[this](http://www.newton.dep.anl.gov/askasci/phy05/phy05163.htm)**

Answer (score 0):

What you have drawn isn't a *circuit*, i.e., there is no *closed* path for an electric current.

Assume that there *is* a steady electric current through the bulb.  Then, electric charge must be leaving one battery and arriving at the other - one battery is steadily becoming negatively charged and the other is steadily becoming positively charged.

But the increasing electric field from such an arrangement would act to *reduce* the electric current until it was zero.

Thus, the original assumption that there is a steady electric current is false.