# Could this open electric circuit work?

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, batteries

[image]

Two batteries are interfaced by a resistor. Parameters such as resistance can be set arbitrarily. Does it work?

Comment: It does, and you get a current flowing (rightward) of amount $I = (V_A - V_B)/R$. If that number comes out negative, it means current flows leftward. But I don't see any reason why this shouldn't work. Your resistor should be able to dissipate at least as much power as $I^2R$ in order for this to work without overheating (that is, it's power rating of your resistor should be at least that $I^2R$).

Comment: Could you update the drawing to include the other pole of each battery? Would make it much more clear.

Comment: @eqb, In the case of battery, there is no predefined potential of the terminals, What is important for the battery is the potential difference between its terminals. And If some electrons enter a battery through one terminal, same number of electrons should leave through the other terminal too . As the circuit is not complete this will not happen. Although there will be some current initially for very short time, for the normal action of battery the circuit should be closed. You should go through Lubos Motl answer.

Comment: My apologies. I was misled by the absence of the other poles in the drawing -- I assumed they were connected. If the other terminals are not connected together, then indeed no current flows save for some transients due to possible potential difference between the poles of batteries A and B.

Answer (score 3):

No, there won't be any persistent current going through the resistor.

There will only be some current for a tiny period of time. This will bring the poles of the left battery to potentials $0,V_1$, and those of the right battery to $V_1,V_1+V_2$. Note that the electrostatic potential of both poles of the two batteries that are connected to the resistor will quickly be the same. There is no contradiction in saying that the potential is the same on both connected poles because the potentials on the other, disconnected poles of both batteries are arbitrary.

There won't be any persistent current because the charge clearly can't accumulate on one side indefinitely. Almost all macroscopic objects in the real world are almost exactly electrically neutral; otherwise they would carry a huge electrostatic energy that Nature tries to avoid. Normally, with a single battery, the charge that would get through the resistor would run in loops: it would "get back" through the battery itself. If the loop is cut because the other poles of the batteries are not connected, the current is impossible.

After all, you may simply imagine that the resistance of your resistor is $R=0$. You can connect the batteries directly. That will be equivalent to having one battery with the combined voltage, something that everyone who has used any gadget with AAA batteries knows very well. Two 1.5 V batteries behind one another (in series) just give you one 3 V battery, and so on. But no current is flowing if nothing is connected to this (single or combined) battery.

Comment: And what about lightening? Is lightening complete circuit?

Comment: I would say Yes. The air becomes conductive at the place of the lightning, like a wire, and it discharges the voltage between the ground and the cloud. So it is similar to your picture except that the cloud and the ground are better compared to a capacitor rather than a batter - yes, I really mean that the ground/cloud are two opposite poles of the *same* capacitor, so it's closed. At any rate, this capacitor is discharged by the lightning.

Answer (score 0):

No,
there will be no current through the resistor.

There is no potential difference between it's ends.
There is a diference between the poles of each battery, but I see no reason why threre should be a voltage difference and current on the resistor. Both batteries create a potential difference relative to the resistor.

It could be changed to have a connection from the right, or the left side of the resistor to some ground potential.
That would not actually change anything;
But it would be easier to see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

The question has already been answered but I would like to provide another from a slightly different perspective.

Imagine that the unconnected battery terminals were connected together via another resistor:

[image]

Now, there *is* an electric current circulating counter-clockwise and given by

$$I = \frac{V_{BAT A} +  V_{BAT B}}{R_1 + R_2}$$

Clearly, if we *increase* the value of $R_2$, the current *decreases* and, if we increase the value to infinity (remove $R_2$ from the circuit), we have the 'circuit' in your question.  But then,

$$I =  \frac{V_{BAT A} +  V_{BAT B}}{R_1 + \infty} = 0$$

Thus, there is zero current  - *it does not work*.